# Building a fresh form using Zend\Form\Form

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to build a fresh form to add user accounts to the web-app and to achieve that I'm trying to do that via Zend\Form\Form. How do I please to write this html code using Zend\Form\Form:

```
<form method="post" action="./ajouter">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="identifiant">Identifiant</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="identifiant" id="identifiant" value="" placeholder="Entrez l'identifiant" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="motDePasse">Mot-de-passe</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="motDePasse" id="motDePasse" value="" placeholder="Entrez le mot-de-passe" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="role">Rôle</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="role" id="role">
            <option value="administrateur" selected>Administrateur</option>
            <option value="membre">Membre</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ajouter</button><a href="../compte" style="margin-left:5px;">Retourner à la liste</a>
</form>
```

Here is a skeleton that you can start with:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Form;

use Zend\Form\Form;

class AddAccountForm extends Form{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->setName('adduser');
        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    }
}

?>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Right, i'll just do your work for you. There is [allot of documentation on forms](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#quick-start), if you can be bothered to read it.

Comment: @AlexP, but how to create a `<div></div>` tag using Forms ?

Comment: read the docs to create the form the use the bootstrap bundle module https://github.com/neilime/zf2-twb-bundle to render the form

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reproduce one form into which are put a div and a button one using Zend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24731399/how-to-reproduce-one-form-into-which-are-put-a-div-and-a-button-one-using-zend)